# How to reuse HOC Redux component with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have a Component that I'd like to use in like 10 apps. But the problem is that I don't want to connect the component in each app. Because they would all basically do the same thing.

I was thinking to create wrapper function on the HOC and pass the root selector object (that contains a tree of selectors functions that are similar in each app) from each app, but the problem is that it gets way too complex and I don't feel is right.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough without actual code. Is there a reason why you can't `connect` it once and use in 10 apps? *the problem is that it gets way too complex* - what exactly did you try?

Comment: Why don't you just provide a base variant of the component that is shared across all apps and those that want to apply Redux' `connect` to it should just export their scoped HoC?

Comment: @estus each application can have a different appState, therefore if is connected at the library level the selector can be used for different apps.